# Is there a efficient way to do multiple test cases in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing

I use MS Visual Studio and I am new to C++, so I am just wondering if there is an faster more efficient way to do multiple test cases instead of keep clicking CTRL+F5 and re-opening the console many times.

Like for example if I have this code

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
int x;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<x*2<<endl;
}
```

Is there a way I could try different values of x at once and getting the results together?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: `void main` isn't legal C++, by the way.

Comment: Testing what? Your program? Its result for different inputs?

Comment: It's C++. Sorry about the title. Edited it now. I think loops will do what I want. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple work around:

```
while(terminating_condition_is_not_met)
{
     execute_what_you_want
}
```

terminating condition can be EOF or max_no_of_iterations or some_sentinel_value

And for your code, I used `-1` as a sentinel.

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
 int x;
 while(1)
 {
 cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
 cin>>x;
 if(x==-1)
    break;
 cout<<x*2<<endl; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `while(how_many_times_you_want)` is not the best pseudocode for explanation. `while(1)` won't run once.